# g++ build errors with node-gyp rebuild for Node.js Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, g++, node-gyp

Here is my bindings.gyp file:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "hello",
      "sources": [ "hello.cpp" ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
      ],
       "cflags" : [ "-std=c++1", "-stdlib=libc++" ],
              "conditions": [
                [ "OS!='win'", {
                  "cflags+": [ "-std=c++11" ],
                  "cflags_c+": [ "-std=c++11" ],
                  "cflags_cc+": [ "-std=c++11" ],
                }],
                [ "OS=='mac'", {
                  "xcode_settings": {
                    "OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS" : [ "-std=c++11", "-stdlib=libc++" ],
                    "OTHER_LDFLAGS": [ "-stdlib=libc++" ],
                    "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET": "10.7"
                  },
                }],
              ],
    }
  ]
}
```

when running

```
sudo node-gyp rebuild
```

I get these errors:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/replace-line/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/hello/hello.o
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++1’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
hello.target.mk:106: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/hello/hello.o' failed
```

from the error trace, seems clear that we are using g++ not gcc, and my g++ version is:

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

and yep I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Does anyone know why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `-std=c++1`, which is a typo, it should be: `-std=c++11`.

Also, `-stdlib` is a clang option (not g++). For g++ libstdc++ is always used.

Comment: ok thanks, but here we are talking about g++ not gcc? I frankly don't know the difference